# Is there any mail service accepting real id?

Tags: email, identity

Most webmail services like gmail, facebook, yahoo,.. allow anonymous to create a mail address.

If there is a security breach, user may lost important information on that address. They may add phone number as a security layer, but even phone number can be lost and not guarantee security (in many countries, anonymous phone number is allowed, so who own that number is maybe a legal issue) and important address may have important info relating to business.

Is there any service allow for claiming an address with real ID?

Comment: Accepting an id how?  During signup?  Remember that most web-portals are designed with quick turnaround times in mind, and adding anything to do with a real id would increase that.  Among many, _many_ other problems.  During login?  Some businesses use smart-cards, which contain additional authentication factors (private key, probably).  Since these can be lost too, they usually just have a password (potentially unique).  What's your expected use-case here?  Can you give us more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example is Italy's "Posta Certificata": a web mail that *by law* guarantees the recipient is a real person:

https://www.postacertificata.gov.it/home/index.dot

To activate it you need to go to a post office and provide an ID card.

This shifts the problem to a different domain:

- ID cards and all their associated issues: how can we be sure that the Post Office operator knows how to recognize a fake ID? What if it's an insider job? Etc.
- What if an attacker takes control of a citizen's web browser?

In the end your mileage may vary depending on what your definition of a real ID is.

Answer (score 0):

Any service you pay for has to know your billing and CC information.  They also care who you are because if they stop providing service to you, they stop getting money.